# Angularjs/Javascript : Print Genreated tabular data with css from webpage to print

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, printing, pagination

Please find the below screenshot for reference:

[image: Tabular data with css]

I need to print the above section with css in a different window(print preview) and then print dialog with default printer should come up.

I tried to print via iframe or simple hidden div but the rendered html doesnt have the css part and it looks like below:

[image: printed data]

The challenge is that the css is not affecting on the print preview window and images as well. How can i efficiently handle it via javascript or angularjs as the table is loaded by angualrjs scope ng-repeat.

Also, the paginated data should be one full page in the print preview.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Is all of that data already loaded into something on the scope? You just need to pass it into some other directive that handles the new window and print functionality.

Comment: Data is loaded via scope variable but we are ng-repeat and using ng-table and ngtableparams we are paginating.. if we use the same then it will print one page. Directive approach is not known to me.. can u elaborate @mcpDESIGNS

Answer (score 0):

This will help alot.

```
var divToPrint = document.getElementById('SomeDivId');
var newWin = window.open('', 'Print-Window');
newWin.document.open();
newWin.document.write('<html><head>' + document.head.innerHTML + '</head><body onload="window.print();setTimeout(function(){window.close();}, 100);">' + divToPrint.innerHTML + '</body></html>'); newWin.document.close();
```

Use this it will work like a charm.